# How to "get" a reliable parallel port on a laptop without a PCMCIA slot?

Tags: printer, parallel-port

Usb-Parallel port (for an old, but reliable matrix printer that has its special use) connections (cables) are unreliable. They sometimes work, sometimes don't - and since I installed Windows 7 I can't get neither of my old ones to work properly.

PCMCIA is usually considered (and it is) a much more *reliable* solution, but unfortunatelly, none of my new laptops has a PCMCIA slot.

So, all ideas are welcomed. What should I do? I'm open to all suggestions as long as you have some experience that they work more reliably than USB-Parallel cables and their wicked drivers.

Comment: You said *PCMCIA*, so I am assuming a laptop. In which case: Does your laptop come with a connector for a docking port? (My experience with 'legacy replicator' docks for serial and paralel ports so far has been positive.)

Comment: @Hennes - unfortunatelly, no.

Comment: You could try a small print server. I don't know how reliable they are though.